# Unable to deploy app on firebase using Google Cloud build ! Getting error "exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: devops, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

Hi I am trying to automate task of deployment using Google Cloud build to trigger the build & deploy whenever code is pushed into master branch .

But I am getting error , in the step 2 of the build ( Deploy step )

*"exec user process caused "no such file or directory"*

Here are my Files :

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
    steps:
# Install node packages
- name: node:12.13.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']

# Build productive files
- name: node:12.13.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: [ 'run', 'build', '--prod' ]
# Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: ['deploy', '--project', 'dive-testing-268508', '--token', 'YYY']
```

Where YYY is repalced with token value ,

**firebase.json**

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "ocean-aifrontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

output path in **angular.json**

```
    "outputPath": "dist",
```

I am unable to understand the root cause behind this !Please let me know if any further info is required for sorting this issue . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The source of this error might be due to the entrypoint for Docker in your `firebase.bash` file is set up for Windows, not Linux.

You may want to take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/issues/224#issuecomment-487419903) and how it was resolved.